# Генерация Angular-компонента без CLI

Tags: angular

Всем привет!
Сейчас я пилю гибридное приложение AngularJS + Angular.
Проблема следующая: гибридное приложение необходимо собирать(билдить) без AngularCLI, но вот как мне тогда создавать компоненты? Папку с четыремя файлами, в каждом из которых надо прописать отсылки друг к другу? Без CLI я не могу применить инструменты в стиле ng generate .
Кто-нибудь знает обходные пути? Чтобы создавать компоненты просто и не боясь забыть где-то в одном месте исправить что-то необходимое.
Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вряд ли такое существует. CLI как раз и является тем инструментом, что решает задачу программной генерации компонентов. Думаю, у вас только 3 пути: 1. Написать программу, которая будет генерировать вам файлы. 2. Найти в исходниках ангуляра код генерации и скопировать его себе. 3. Таки использовать CLI. По идее не обязательно им собирать проект для того, чтобы использовать его фичу генерации файлов.